# zeromq socket recv hanging

Tags: c++, zeromq, freeze

I use zeromq (latest version, 2012.04.04), c++, ms vs 2008 (x86 release/debug), windows 7 x64. I try to code simple client-server system.

### Problem

My problem is **dead hanging of the computer** at recv() command on Windows 7, when *many clients connect to the server at the same time*.

On Windows Vista the result is like on Windows XP - client has the fail:
http://research.makseq.com/testZMQ/2.Vista.png
http://research.makseq.com/testZMQ/1.PNG
After this fail clients can not connect to the server, they write:
"Assertion fail: Address already in use: ..."

### Here is source code:

http://research.makseq.com/testZMQ/testZMQ.rar

### How to use:

1) "testZMQ.exe server" to server start,

2) press enter and hold at "testZMQ.exe" to start many-many-many clients.

Try to start the server multiple times: I think this bug happens when the server started two and more times.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "../Libraries/zeromq/include/zmq.h"
#include "../Libraries/zeromq/include/zhelpers.hpp"
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

#ifdef WIN32
#pragma comment(lib, "../Libraries/zeromq/libzmq.lib") 
#endif

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int server()
{
    cout << ":: Server ::" << endl;
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t server(context, ZMQ_REP);
    server.bind("tcp://*:7774");

    while (1) {

         // receive 
         zmq::message_t messageR;
         cout << "debug point 1" << endl; 
         server.recv(&messageR); // <== dead hanging here
         cout << "debug point 2" << endl; 
         string recieved = string(static_cast<char*>(messageR.data()), messageR.size());

         // send
         string reply = "do something";
         zmq::message_t messageS(reply.size());
         memcpy(messageS.data(), reply.data(), reply.size()); 
         cout << "debug point 3" << endl; 
         server.send(messageS);
         cout << "debug point 4" << endl; 

    }
    return 0;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int client()
{
    cout << ":: Client ::" << endl;
    // connect
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t *client = new zmq::socket_t (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    client->connect("tcp://localhost:7774");
    int linger = 0;
    client->setsockopt (ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof (linger));

    // send
    string reply = "hello";
    zmq::message_t messageS(reply.size());
    memcpy(messageS.data(), reply.data(), reply.size()); 
    client->send(messageS);

    // receive
    zmq::message_t messageR;
    client->recv(&messageR);
    string recieved = string(static_cast<char*>(messageR.data()), messageR.size());

    // close
    client->close();
    delete client;
    zmq_term(&context);

    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) server(); 
    else client(); 

    return 0;
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`recv` is a blocking call. Until something connects, it will sit there and wait. It's not a *dead hang*, it's just waiting for a connection.

Comment: m.. i can't do anything: move the mouse, start any program or close my program. My computer is hanging wholly..

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a way bigger issue than something ZMQ is doing. Have you tried the same thing on another machine? Do you have the same problem with the same compiled binary? Can you post your full source code?

Comment: Yes, i have tried this thing on another machines! and the result is the same: wholly hanging! The problem is staying with different builds: x86 debug, x86 release...

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll give that a spin when I get home. BTW, have you tried binding to a single interface/IP address instead of the wildcard to see if that works?

Comment: No, I don't try it, but I think the result will be equavallent :)

Comment: I have tested it on Window XP. There is NO dead haning, but error on client side was: http://research.makseq.com/testZMQ/1.PNG

Comment: On Windows Vista the result is like on Windows XP
(client has the fail):
http://research.makseq.com/testZMQ/2.Vista.png

After this fail NO ONE client can connect to the server, they write: "Assertion fail: Address already in use: ..."

Answer (score 0):

The "Address already in use" error seems to imply your call to socket.bind() is happening multiple times - i.e. you're running more than one server process. You can only bind once to a given port on a given interface.

I doubt that explains why it causes the machine to hang though...