# Why does ZeroMQ's socket.recv call hang in the following code?

Tags: f#, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I have encountered a problem with a simple pub-sub example in ZeroMQ.  I have read plenty of documentation, but I cannot seem to find an answer.

I got `libzmq` and `clrzmq` from NuGet.  For both the functions below the socket address is:

```
let sktAddr = "tcp://127.0.0.1:3456"
```

Here is a simple publisher, that queues a message every second.

```
// Publisher - this seems to work fine
let publisher () : unit =
    let skt = (new ZMQ.Context()).Socket(ZMQ.SocketType.PUB)
    skt.SetSockOpt(ZMQ.SocketOpt.LINGER, 0)
    skt.Bind sktAddr
    skt.SendMore("TEST_TOPIC", Text.Encoding.Unicode) |> ignore
    let rec h1 () : unit =
        let nv = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString()
        printfn "Sending value: %s" nv
        skt.Send(Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes nv) |> ignore
        Threading.Thread.Sleep 1000
        let swt = new Threading.SpinWait()
        swt.SpinOnce()
        if Console.KeyAvailable then
            match Console.ReadKey().Key with
            | ConsoleKey.Q -> ()
            | _ -> h1()
        else
            h1()
    h1()
```

The following simple subscriber throws no error, but hangs at the line indicated below.

```
// Subscriber
let subscriber () : unit =
    let skt = (new ZMQ.Context()).Socket(ZMQ.SocketType.SUB)
    skt.Connect sktAddr
    skt.Subscribe("TEST_TOPIC", Text.Encoding.Unicode)
    let rec h1 () : unit =
        let oDat = skt.Recv() // THE PROGRAMME HANGS HERE!
        let strODat = (new Text.UnicodeEncoding()).GetString oDat
        if oDat <> null then
            printfn "Received: %s" strODat
        else
            printfn "No data received"
        let swt = new System.Threading.SpinWait()
        swt.SpinOnce()
        if Console.KeyAvailable then
            match Console.ReadKey().Key with
            | ConsoleKey.Q -> ()
            | _ -> h1()
        else
            h1()
    h1()
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258867/zeromq-socket-recv-hanging), but no solution is provided.  So I am posting a new question here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is `tNa` in `skt.Subscribe(tNa, Text.Encoding.Unicode)`?

Comment: @raffian, sorry, I have just edited my code and replaced `tNa` with the intended value, `TEST_TOPIC`.  This was just an error in the question.  In the actual code, all the variables have appropriate values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the publisher:

`skt.SendMore("TEST_TOPIC", Text.Encoding.Unicode)`

Not knowing F#, it appears the above statement happens outside the loop. If the subscriber is listening on `TEST_TOPIC`, any messages originating from the publisher require the topic name to precede content for each message, so the publisher must do this each time it sends:

```
skt.SendMore("TEST_TOPIC", Text.Encoding.Unicode)
skt.Send("some data here", Text.Encoding.Unicode)
```

..try this...

```
let publisher () : unit =
    let skt = (new ZMQ.Context()).Socket(ZMQ.SocketType.PUB)
    skt.SetSockOpt(ZMQ.SocketOpt.LINGER, 0)
    skt.Bind sktAddr

    let rec h1 () : unit =
        let nv = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString()
        printfn "Sending value: %s" nv
        skt.SendMore("TEST_TOPIC", Text.Encoding.Unicode) |> ignore
        skt.Send(Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes nv) |> ignore
        Threading.Thread.Sleep 1000
        let swt = new Threading.SpinWait()
        swt.SpinOnce()
        if Console.KeyAvailable then
            match Console.ReadKey().Key with
            | ConsoleKey.Q -> ()
            | _ -> h1()
        else
            h1()
    h1()
```

..and the subscriber has to receive twice for each message:

```
// Subscriber
let subscriber () : unit =
    let skt = (new ZMQ.Context()).Socket(ZMQ.SocketType.SUB)
    skt.Connect sktAddr
    skt.Subscribe("TEST_TOPIC", Text.Encoding.Unicode)
    let rec h1 () : unit =
        let topicName = skt.Recv()
        let oDat = skt.Recv()
        let strODat = (new Text.UnicodeEncoding()).GetString oDat
        if oDat <> null then
            printfn "Received: %s" strODat
        else
            printfn "No data received"
        let swt = new System.Threading.SpinWait()
        swt.SpinOnce()
        if Console.KeyAvailable then
            match Console.ReadKey().Key with
            | ConsoleKey.Q -> ()
            | _ -> h1()
        else
            h1()
    h1()
```

Comment: if I could vote your answer up a hundred times, I would!  Thank you so much!